# How to elegantly access Android Views from other thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4j  in asynchronous mode. When I get response in Listener I want to be able to change some Views in my Activity but it results in `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

I know that I can use `runOnUiThread` method, but what is the most elegant solution for this apart from inlining Runnable Classes?

Part of my Activity:

```
    TwitterListener listener = new TwitterAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void gotUserDetail(User user) {
            super.gotUserDetail(user);

            fillInUserProfileDetails(user);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any more "elegant" solution than `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)` or `View.post(Runnable)`. You've probably already seen the discussion of threading in the Android docs:

**EDIT:**
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

As stated there, the Android UI toolkit is not threadsafe, so all interaction with it must occur on the same thread, namely the application's UI thread; and if you're going to pass work from one thread to another, you will need a Runnable object to encapsulate the work to be performed.

I know that anonymous inner classes can look rather messy, but they are quite a common idiom in Java, since they are the closest thing to [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296249/closure-definition-and-example) available in the language. So the best thing for you to do, IMO, is grit your teeth and use `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`, and remind yourself that elegance is in the eye of the programmer.